# Set class property that not define as global from other method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have issue that i am tying to solve.

I have an `winform application` and in my main form (public partial class MainWin : Form) i am try to avoid using global variables.

I have Play button click that in that event i am create my class who hanle my files from my `Listbox`.

Inside this class i have property that if i want to stop immediatly i just set this value to false but because i am not save my class as global i cannot access this class from `stop button event`.

Can i use some other way to access this class or there is no other way despite to save my class as global ?

```
ListBox listBoxFiles;

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBoxFiles.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        myClass class = new MyClass();
        class.play...
    }
}

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // i cannot reach myClass from here
    }
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: You need a reference to `myClass` at the class level, not in the local method scope.

Comment: Can i have an example ?

Comment: How about a public static property in MyClass?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you might be overthinking this, because it's rather hard to define "global variables" in C#, compared to languages like C/C++.

The variable, whether it's a member of a property, is only defined within the scope of the class. It is not readily accessible outside that class, unless you have the class' reference and the member is (of course) public.

So create as many variables as you'd like within the Application class.

Answer (score 0):

How about a public static property in MyClass which is not a variable in its usual sense like:

```
public static Boolean play { get; set; }
```

Then can be access as :

```
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyClass.play = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a reference to your MyClass object unless you store its reference and make it available to the btnStop_Click event handler. The scope of your MyClass objects are currently limited within the btnPlay_Click method only.

Since you are instantiating a new instance of MyClass for each of your listBoxFiles.Items, one way of achieving this would be to maintain a list of the MyClass instances (or a dictionary of item/MyClass) and use the same in your btnStop_Click event hander.

```
private List<MyClass> listMyClass = new List<MyClass>();

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBoxFiles.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        myClass classObj = new MyClass();
        listMyClass.Add(classObj); //store the reference
        classObj.play...
    }
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(var obj in listMyClass)
   {
    obj.play = false; //do wahatever you want to do with your MyClass object
   }       

}
```